# Unity Strange FPS drops on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile

When you start the game on Android, about 40 fps is displayed, but after a while (from 1-2 seconds to several minutes) the fps levels off and becomes stable at 60 (the phone just supports update frequency 60). Also, if I minimize and reopen the game, I get 40 fps back. Even if you disable all objects and scripts, leaving only the camera and the FPS counter, the situation remains exactly the same (even turned off the GUI itself). I reviewed many optimization solutions and none of them solved the problem. I noticed an interesting coincidence, if you connect the charger and immediately turn it off, then the fps immediately equalizes to 60.

Profiler:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIf9S.jpg

Unity: 2022.2.7f1
Phone: Redmi Note 7. Tested on 4 different phones (of which 3 had such a problem) and only on a more
powerful one with a hertz of 120 remained stable 120.

```
Application.targetFrameRate limit = 280;
```

Project settings: All static objects are set to Static. Shader: Mobile/Difuse, Mobile/. Graphics API: tried everything possible (OpenGLES 3, OpenGLES 2, Vulkan).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQwOs.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugEIw.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIVqD.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/99i2D.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/29bdU.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DKFF.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXTvs.jpg

Comment: Have you tried attaching the profiler?

Comment: In profiler:
Gfx.WaitForPresentOnGfxThread - Semaphore.WaitForSignal: 56.4%
Camera.Render: 15%
FixedUpdate.PhysicsFixedUpdate: 7.1%
UIEvents.CanvasManagerRenderOverlays 3.3%

for all this, it seemed to me that Semaphore.WaitForSignal was eating all the resources, but I read that it only waits, which means that the problem is probably not in it